# Rails datetime parameters in time zone parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncontroller

Suppose I have a form that returns a date and a time_zone.

```
params = { date: "2016-08-23T16:30:00+00:00", time_zone: "Paris" }
```

I am then using those params in my controller to build an object

```
Meeting = Meeting.build(params.require(:meeting).permit(:date, :time_zone))
```

Now the problem is browsers will often return a date with different time zone. In the example : the user meant to build an appointment at 16H30 in the Paris (GTM+2) time_zone (so `14:30 GMT+0`), but the form ended up supplying the +00 offset so we need to get the offset from "Paris", and change `16:30+00` into `16:30+02`

What's the fastest way to do that ? (Several other answers explain how to do in in general Ruby, I am more interested in the specific Rails/ActionController scope.

Comment: Is it always Paris, or do the timezones vary?

Comment: It is a parameter, so yes it changes

Comment: sry - didn't see that. What if you stipulate that your db store timezones. It's not storing the offset like you specifically asked for, but it might still solve the issue?